Fixing 403 on Chrome Web Store Publish API
I'm trying to publish a chrome extension using the Chrome Web Store Publish API. I've created a Google Cloud project and an OAuth 2 client as per
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/using-api
My user has 2 factor authentication set up. I've even set up billing to be sure.
But the step https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/XXXX is returning
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Forbidden",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ]
    }
}

I have no clue how to move forward here as I have no clue what is missing for me to be authorized.
Any clues on how to solve this ? Or may be access the logs giving more information on why a 403 was sent ?
